# Locally compact space $X$, $C_b(X)$ is reflexive if and only if $X$ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Taken From Conway's A Course in Functional Analysis Chapter 3 Section 11 Problem 2

Problem Statement: Show that for a locally compact space $X$, $C_b(X)$ is reflexive if and only if $X$ is finite.

$C_b(X)$ is the set of all continuous functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ such that $||f|| = \sup\{|f(x)|: x \in X\}< \infty$. However, from here I'm not sure how to prove this is reflexive.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $X$ is infinite (and Hausdorff), let $\{V_n\}_n$ be a family of pairwise disjoint, non-empty open subsets of $X$.  For each $n$, choose a continuous function $f_n$ of norm one, vanishing off $V_n$.  Next show that the closed subspace generated by the $f_n$ is isometrically isomorphic to $c_0$.  Since $c_0$ is not reflexive, neither is $X$.